# Whatever it takes / took?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

"As far as he was concerned it was the discovery of the millennium, and he was prepared to do whatever it *took/takes* to find investment."

Any knowledgeable takes on the matter?

Answer (score 4):

In the most cases you use "whatever it took" because it is about the past, however, it can be "whatever it takes" in the special/particular context when the present tense is used to describe the law, laws of nature,  the universal rule, the phenomenon which occurs constantly when the universe exists. So, the context also determines the meaning, and the grammar just helps to express it.

Answer (score 3):

"Takes" is present tense and cannot be used here, but (as you note) "took" is awkward, so I'd rearrange the sentence to avoid the issue:

> he was prepared to do *whatever it would take* to find investment.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be *takes* as it is already in the past. So: *took*.

Comment: will it be more embarrassing to delete the question or leave it?

Comment: You don't need to delete it, it's bound to get out of focus pretty soon (if that's what you're worried about).

Comment: @joeav: You really should have asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), not here. In fact, Darius's answer is more correct, and should get all the upvotes from other ELU users. But the *text* of his answer probably isn't particularly easy for a *learner* to follow.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you would have done better with a "yes". as an answer to my comment above. sounds like you have the website charter open in your lap or something

Comment: @joeav Are you saying that you think FF's attempts to stick within the remit of the website are in some way toxic? Wouldn't this strike you as being the attitude of a scofflaw?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth any particular reason why you're continuing this here? it's a shame because I practically answered your cryptic question back in the 'clutching comments'. In short - the website gives you tools to vote content up or down. If you are unhappy with the results, you think you're getting an influx of users like me, you're welcome to take it up with management, and suggest better filtering mechanisms. Relying on FuFu here to scare people off isn't much of a stopgap measure. You're just being dick and cronies. Scofflaw: prohibition era term, when laws ignored reality- fits well.